# Prevent user from logging in directly to windows 2003 server but allow workstation and RDP log in?

Tags: windows

I want to be able to prevent a user from sitting down directly at our server and log in but allow them to remote desktop in or log in from workstation. We are on a domain with windows 2003 server.

Comment: What do you mean "log in from workstation"?

Comment: Microsoft ended support for Windows Server 2003 in July 2015. That means no security patches anymore. You really don't want users to be logging into this machine with RDP either. In fact, you probably don't want this machine connected to the internet at all!

Comment: The RDP is done through a VPN so not worried about security, the internet is cut off to any internet traffic other that RDP on a different port. I just want to stop someone fro walking up to server and log in to our server, I want them to use their workstation or RDP.

Answer (score 3):

There are four Group Policies that will do exactly what you want:

- [Allow log on locally](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/allow-log-on-locally)
- [Deny log on locally](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/deny-log-on-locally)
- [Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/allow-log-on-through-remote-desktop-services)
- [Deny log on through Remote Desktop Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/deny-log-on-through-remote-desktop-services)

By combining them, you can define which users (or groups) can (and cannot) log on to the server console and/or via Remote Desktop.

All of them can be found in `Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment`

Comment: Can you deny local log in to server without it denying the domain log on through their workstation? Will the deny local log on prevent the RDP log on to the server?

Comment: Yes to all. You can deny local logon and allow RDP logon, or vice-versa, or any combination of them.